# Bullets aren't shooting at the EXACT position of mouse :(

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm writing a game with pygame where a player runs away from zombie blocks and shoots them to kill them. I have the bullets shooting towards my mouse position which is what I want. However, the bullets seem to only be able to shoot from about 10 different axis' instead of anywhere in a 360 degree circle. How do I fix this to make it so the bullets always go straight to the mouse cursor instead of close to it?

-Here is my whole program so you can copy / paste it to try out the game. Notice how the bullets don't follow the mouse position exactly. How can this be fixed? The code for the bullets will be posted below the whole game code. WASD to move, mouse to aim and shoot, press 'P' to quit:

```
import pygame
import math
import random

BLACK  = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE  = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN  = (0, 255, 0)
RED    = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE   = (0, 0, 255)
ORANGE = (255, 119, 0)
ZOMBIE_GREEN = (122, 172, 34)

cursor_x = 100
cursor_y = 100

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()

        # pygame.Surface will create a rectangle with the width and height given
        # and the command below it tells it to fill it in with that color
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # This defines the starting position (x, y)
        # of whatever sprite is passed through
        self.rect.x = 600
        self.rect.y = 300

        # This is the current speed it will move when drawn
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None

    # Defines how the player will move
    def movement(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y


    # Updates the information so the screen shows the player moving
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        # Did this update cause us to hit a wall?
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # If we are moving right, set our right side to the left side of
            # the item we hit
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            else:
                # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y
        # Check and see if we hit anything
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.walls, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:

            # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(35, screen_width - 35)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(35, screen_height - 135)
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.walls = None

    def movement(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

class Cursor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.walls = None

    # This updates the cursor to move along with your
    # mouse position (defined in control logic)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x = cursor_x
        self.rect.y = cursor_y

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([8, 8])
        self.image.fill(ORANGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = player.rect.x + 4
        self.rect.y = player.rect.y + 4

        self.walls = None
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def bullet_movement(self, cursor_pos_x, cursor_pos_y, player_pos_x, player_pos_y):
        bullet_vec_x = cursor.rect.x - player.rect.x
        bullet_vec_y = cursor.rect.y - player.rect.y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(bullet_vec_x ** 2 + bullet_vec_y ** 2) # Normalizing the Vector
        bullet_vec_x = (bullet_vec_x / vec_length) * 5 # These numbers determine how
        bullet_vec_y = (bullet_vec_y / vec_length) * 5 # fast the bullets travel
        self.change_x += bullet_vec_x
        self.change_y += bullet_vec_y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

pygame.init()

screen_size = pygame.display.Info()

#size = (900, 700)
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

size = (screen_size.current_w, screen_size.current_h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
    ((screen_size.current_w, screen_size.current_h)),pygame.FULLSCREEN
    )

screen_width = screen_size.current_w
screen_height = screen_size.current_h

pygame.display.set_caption("Zombie Shooter")



wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Walls are made here = (x_coord for where it starts,
# y_coord for where it starts, width of wall, height of wall)
# These walls are made with fullscreen dimentions, not any set dimentions
# Left
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, 0, 10, screen_height)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# Top
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, 0, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# Bottom
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, screen_height - 10, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# Right
wall = Wall(BLUE, screen_width - 10, 0, 10, screen_width)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)
# HUD Border
wall = Wall(BLUE, 0, screen_height - 100, screen_width, 10)
wall_list.add(wall)
all_sprites_list.add(wall)

# This creates the actual player with the parameters set in ( ).
# However, we must add the player to the all_sprites_list
# so that it will actually be drawn to the screen with the draw command
# placed right after the screen.fill(BLACK) command.
player = Player(WHITE)
player.walls = wall_list
all_sprites_list.add(player)

cursor = Cursor(7, 7)
cursor.walls = wall_list
all_sprites_list.add(cursor)

zombie = Enemy(ZOMBIE_GREEN)
for i in range(10):
    zombie = Enemy(ZOMBIE_GREEN)
    all_sprites_list.add(zombie)
    sprites_list.add(zombie)

bullet = Bullet()




done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:

    # --- Main event loop ---
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                done = True

        # Keyboard controls. The numbers inside change the speed of the player
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movement(-4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movement(4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.movement(0, -4)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.movement(0, 4)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movement(4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movement(-4, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                player.movement(0, 4)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                player.movement(0, -4)

        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        cursor_x = pos[0]
        cursor_y = pos[1]

        if cursor_x <= 10:
            cursor_x = 10
        if cursor_x >= (screen_width - 17):
            cursor_x = (screen_width - 17)

        if cursor_y <= 10:
            cursor_y = 10
        if cursor_y >= (screen_height - 107):
            cursor_y = (screen_height - 107)

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullet = Bullet()
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)
            bullet.bullet_movement(cursor.rect.x, cursor.rect.y, player.rect.x, player.rect.y)

    all_sprites_list.update()

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, sprites_list, True)
        for i in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, wall_list, False)
        for i in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    # .update() will 'update' or change the screen with what
    # we've told it to everytime we run throught the loop. Without
    # this our player would not appear to move on the screen because
    # we wouldn't be telling the screen to change the coordinates of the player.
    cursor.update()
    bullet_list.update()



    screen.fill(BLACK)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Here's how the bullet vector's are calculated. Can this be edited to make the bullets more accurately go towards the red cursor position?

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([8, 8])
        self.image.fill(ORANGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.x = player.rect.x + 4
        self.rect.y = player.rect.y + 4

        self.walls = None
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def bullet_movement(self, cursor_pos_x, cursor_pos_y, player_pos_x, player_pos_y):
        bullet_vec_x = cursor.rect.x - player.rect.x
        bullet_vec_y = cursor.rect.y - player.rect.y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(bullet_vec_x ** 2 + bullet_vec_y ** 2) # Normalizing the Vector
        bullet_vec_x = (bullet_vec_x / vec_length) * 5 # These numbers determine how
        bullet_vec_y = (bullet_vec_y / vec_length) * 5 # fast the bullets travel
        self.change_x += bullet_vec_x
        self.change_y += bullet_vec_y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

Comment: I don't think the math is calculating what you want for bullet_vec_x and bullet_vec_y

Comment: @ChadSimmons ok, could you you explain? I'd love to get this fixed

Comment: I'm assuming you want the bullet to travel 1/5 of the total distance per update?

Comment: @ChadSimmons I'm not sure, the *5 determines the speed of the bullet. If I change it then the bullet moves at different speeds

Comment: ... you determine the speed of the bullet. For realism it should move at the same speed regardless of the angle you fire it at.

Comment: @ChadSimmons The bullets DO move the same speed whichever direction they are going, that's not the problem. If you play the game you'll notice that the bullets don't always go directly to the mouse cursor, just close to it. It's like the bullets can only shoot out of 10 different angles instead of all 360. I'm trying to see if there is something in my code that I can change to make the bullets go to the cursor EXACTLY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is an integer math issue. At some angles, the velocities you're computing for the bullets require moving a fraction of a pixel in a given direction, but `pygame.rect` only supports integer coordinates.

I'm not exactly sure how Pygame's types are implemented, but I suspect this means the fractional part of the updated position is discarded on each frame. Because many velocity vectors get rounded the same way, you end up with a more limited set of angles than you want.

A solution would be to maintain your own (floating point) position values. Your update code would add the velocity components to the floating point position values, then copy the updated values to the `pygame.rect` coordinates. This way the rounding errors would not accumulate and you'd see the difference between different vectors.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([8, 8])
        self.image.fill(ORANGE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.pos_x = player.rect.x + 4   # Set up pos_x and pos_y here
        self.pos_y = player.rect.y + 4   # rather than rect.x and rect.y

        self.walls = None
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def bullet_movement(self, cursor_pos_x, cursor_pos_y, player_pos_x, player_pos_y):
        bullet_vec_x = cursor.rect.x - player.rect.x
        bullet_vec_y = cursor.rect.y - player.rect.y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(bullet_vec_x ** 2 + bullet_vec_y ** 2)
        bullet_vec_x = (bullet_vec_x / vec_length) * 5
        bullet_vec_y = (bullet_vec_y / vec_length) * 5
        self.change_x += bullet_vec_x
        self.change_y += bullet_vec_y

    def update(self):
        self.pos_x += self.change_x  # Update pos_x and pos_y. They will become floats
        self.pos_y += self.change_y  # which will let them maintain sub-pixel accuracy.

        self.rect.x = self.pos_x  # Copy the pos values into the rect, where they will be
        self.rect.y = self.pos_y  # rounded off. That's OK since we never read them back.
```

There are some odds areas of this code, such as the fact that you don't use the arguments to the `bullet_movement` function at all, but rather just look up the global values `player` and `cursor` (you also look up `player` in the `__init__` method). I've not modified those though, but you may want to, once you get the rounding issue under control. I'd also consider merging the code from `bullet_movement` into `__init__`, since there's no situation where you'd want to create a bullet without setting its movement up too.

Comment: First of all thank you for your feedback! What you said makes a lot of sense as to why the bullets only move in limited directions. Would you be able to help me identify what to change in my code to implement what you've suggested? For example you suggested that I maintain my own floating point position values. What do you mean by this and how do I make it happen? This would help me out a lot :)

Comment: I'd change `__init__` to initialize a `pos_x` and a `pos_y` variable instead of `rect.x` and `rect.y`. Then modify `update` to first update `pos_x` and `pos_y` instead of the `rect` vars, but then copy them into the `rect` after they've been updated. E.g.: `self.pos_x += self.change_x; self.rect.x = self.pos_x`

Comment: I changed the `rect.` to `pos_x` and `pos_y` but it no longer has a reference to where the cursor is because it's not taking it's rect. position. Could you maybe change my code to show me what to change specifically?

Comment: @Tanman1276: I've updated with an modified version of your `Bullet` class. I've not tested it, so there may be other issues beyond the design questions I pointed out at the end.

Comment: @ Blckknght You are the bomb, this works SOOOOOOOO  much better and the bullets hit the cursor 99% of the time, thank you so much! You are a life saver! You explained the problem so well and I thank you for taking the time to help a random stranger just coding a video game haha. Thank you so much for your help!